# Why doesn't produceState reflect the data change?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I know that in Android Jetpack Compose, the `produceState` function is used to create a stateful value that can be observed and updated within a Composable function.

In the following code,  I cllick a button to change the value of `isReBindPar`, but I find the text always displays `False`, why?

**ScreenHome.kt**

```
@Composable
fun ScreenHome() {

    Column(
        
    ) {

        val isBindState by produceState(initialValue = false) {
            value = isReBindPar
        }

        Text(isBindState.toString())     //It  always displays False

        Button(
            onClick = {
                isReBindPar = !isReBindPar
            }
        ) {
            Text("Change")
        }
    }

}
```

**PublicPar.kt**

```
var isReBindPar = false
```

**Added Content:**

To Phil Dukhov:  Thanks!

The follwoing content comes from the official [document](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#producestate).

*produceState launches a coroutine scoped to the Composition that can push values into a returned State. Use it to convert non-Compose state into Compose state*

In my mind,  the Compose state variable will changed when the non-Compose variable changed, if not, why does Android Jetpack Compose need to design produceState?

**Added Content Again:**

To Phil Dukhov: Thanks again!

I can use the following code to change  Compose state variable  `isCanAddRecordGlobalState` when the non-Compose variable  `savedFilename` changed.

So again, **why does Android Jetpack Compose need to design produceState?**

```
var isCanAddRecordGlobalState : Boolean by  mutableStateOf(false)

var savedFilename: String by Delegates.observable("") {
        prop, old, new ->  isCanAddRecordGlobalState = new.isNotEmpty()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case when `producer` is called, it instantly reads value from `isReBindPar` which is `false`, and finishes execution

If you want to get an idea in which case it can be used, you can use the following code:

```
val isBindState by produceState(initialValue = false) {
    while (true) {
        value = isReBindPar
        delay(1.seconds)
    }
}
```

So here I prevent `producer` from finishing execution using `while` cycle and update `value` each second - after your click there may be a delay until it updates.

Alternatively, if you change `isReBindPar` type to `MutableStateFlow`: you will be able to call `isReBindPar.collect { value = it }` - in this case it's gonna be an analog of `collectAsState`.

The point is that you can call suspend functions in `producer`, which in my examples are `delay` and `collect` - but generally it can be a database/network request or anything else that needs to be executed asynchronously.

Since it's using `remember` with `LaunchedEffect` under the hood, both the value and the task are not gonna survive configuration change, so I guess it may be ok for a simple database request or fetching `DataStore` value, but not for something heavy.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: @HelloCW there’s no way to track simple value change. This function needed when you have an object that **can** notify about new valie in some way - listener, subscription, etc, but it’s not built in compose same as flows are. E.g if you wanna create wrapper for rx stream, or any other stream

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content again in the question?

Comment: @HelloCW as I said, sometimes you don't control your data layer, and can't just change type to `mutableStateOf` - e.g. you can have legacy code base, or you need to integrate with some old system android API that only gives you updates with listeners.

Answer (score 1):

The produceState function is primarily used for performing asynchronous operations or side effects while updating the state. It is not intended for direct synchronization with another variable.

So you can use the mutableStateOf function

Comment: Thanks! I use these code for testing  produceState